# Is it possible to change all the record's time to UTC to LOCAL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I had the mistake in which I was coding like this

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

In fact, I had to set this

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

However, the service is already started and everything(all the records) is saved with UTC timestamp.

Is it possible to make it :local timestamp all at once?

I have no idea how to optimize this.

Comment: Storing in UTC is actually preferred in many cases because you can simply convert to a user's local time and not have to worry about daylight savings or anything like that. Any reason you don't want to to that?

Comment: @Beerlington when I'm using other tool to access the Database, timestamp should be shown in local time so that it'll be easy to search and think about everything

Comment: What if your production server is in a different timezone?

Comment: @Beerlington it's still the same. The timezone is not UTC. but it still stores everything in UTC time.

Comment: HUSTEN what @Beerlington is saying is that if you use :local you have a dependency on what local means. It is safer (and easier) to just assume everything is utc and then shift them to the locale you need.